# How to get the dependencies working for HtmlUnit

Tags: java, dependencies, htmlunit

I've got to get the HtmlUnit dependencies working by tomorrow to complete a project. I need to use java to access a webpage, fill in a form and click some buttons - HtmlUnit has been recommended for this.

I have downloaded the htmlunit 2.19 bin files which appears to have the jar dependencies and a bunch of documentation on how to use certain features - but there is no 'installation' steps.

Can someone please step me through the installation of the jar dependencies?

I am using Windows 7 and NetBeans IDE 8.0.2.

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. In the libraries menu, I was just adding the folder that contained the jar files. I had to remove that and then add all the jars individually. – Joe
ref: [Java: how to setup htmlunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277544/java-how-to-setup-htmlunit)

Right-click my project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder
Then add each jar individually.

Answer (score -1):

In the downloaded `htmlunit-x.y-bin.zip` file, there is a `lib` folder, which contains all the dependencies.

or you can use maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use maven.

I tried right-clicking my project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder and selecting the lib folder that I downloaded.

I will see if that works.

Otherwise can you be a little more clear on the steps to use maven?